# Algorithm to represent Decision tables

Tags: algorithm, design-decisions

What would be the best algorithm to use if you wanted to store [Decision tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table) in code, i've looked at the Adjacency matrix and Binary tree would anyone consider this to be the right direction? What other choices to I have?

Answer (score 2):

If your focus is on space (for very large decision tables), you might want to consider applying [Binary Decision Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) (BDDs). However, the canonical form would not tell you what action to take, just  provide true/false answers for a large "input" of boolean input variables. This is less powerful than a decision table but very useful for certain applications.